# PowerShell script to monitor IIS logs for 500 errors every 10 minutes

Tags: iis, powershell, iis-7.5, monitoring

I'm trying to set up a script to monitor IIS 7.5 logs fro 500 errors. Now I can get it to do that OK but I would like it to check every 30 minutes. Quite naturally I don't want it to warn me about the previous 500 errors it has already reported.

As you can see from the script below I have added a $time variable to take this into account, however I can't seem to find a way to use this variable. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#Set Time Variable -30
$time = (Get-Date -Format hh:mm:ss (Get-Date).addminutes(-30))
# Location of IIS LogFile
$File = "C:\Users\here\Documents\IIS-log\"+"u_ex"+(get-date).ToString("yyMMdd")+".log"
# Get-Content gets the file, pipe to Where-Object and skip the first 3 lines.
$Log = Get-Content $File | where {$_ -notLike "#[D,S-V]*" }
# Replace unwanted text in the line containing the columns.
$Columns = (($Log[0].TrimEnd()) -replace "#Fields: ", "" -replace "-","" -replace "\(","" -replace "\)","").Split(" ")
# Count available Columns, used later
$Count = $Columns.Length
# Strip out the other rows that contain the header (happens on iisreset)
$Rows = $Log | where {$_ -like "*500 0 0*"}
# Create an instance of a System.Data.DataTable
#Set-Variable -Name IISLog -Scope Global
$IISLog = New-Object System.Data.DataTable "IISLog"
# Loop through each Column, create a new column through Data.DataColumn and add it to the DataTable
foreach ($Column in $Columns) {
  $NewColumn = New-Object System.Data.DataColumn $Column, ([string])
  $IISLog.Columns.Add($NewColumn)
}
# Loop Through each Row and add the Rows.
foreach ($Row in $Rows) {
 $Row = $Row.Split(" ")
 $AddRow = $IISLog.newrow()
 for($i=0;$i -lt $Count; $i++) {
 $ColumnName = $Columns[$i]
 $AddRow.$ColumnName = $Row[$i]
}
 $IISLog.Rows.Add($AddRow)
 }
 $IISLog | select time,csuristem,scstatus
```

OK With KevinD's help and PowerGUI with a fair bit of trial and error, I got it working as I expected. Here's the finished product.

```
#Set Time Variable -30
$time = (Get-Date -Format "HH:mm:ss"(Get-Date).addminutes(-30))
# Location of IIS LogFile
$File = "C:\Users\here\Documents\IIS-log\"+"u_ex"+(get-date).ToString("yyMMdd")+".log"
# Get-Content gets the file, pipe to Where-Object and skip the first 3 lines.
$Log = Get-Content $File | where {$_ -notLike "#[D,S-V]*" }
# Replace unwanted text in the line containing the columns.
$Columns = (($Log[0].TrimEnd()) -replace "#Fields: ", "" -replace "-","" -replace "\(","" -replace "\)","").Split(" ")
# Count available Columns, used later
$Count = $Columns.Length
# Strip out the other rows that contain the header (happens on iisreset)
$Rows = $Log | where {$_ -like "*500 0 0*"}
# Create an instance of a System.Data.DataTable
#Set-Variable -Name IISLog -Scope Global
$IISLog = New-Object System.Data.DataTable "IISLog"
# Loop through each Column, create a new column through Data.DataColumn and add it to the DataTable
foreach ($Column in $Columns) {
  $NewColumn = New-Object System.Data.DataColumn $Column, ([string])
  $IISLog.Columns.Add($NewColumn)
}
# Loop Through each Row and add the Rows.
foreach ($Row in $Rows) {
  $Row = $Row.Split(" ")
  $AddRow = $IISLog.newrow()
  for($i=0;$i -lt $Count; $i++) {
    $ColumnName = $Columns[$i]
    $AddRow.$ColumnName = $Row[$i]
  }
  $IISLog.Rows.Add($AddRow)
  }
  $IISLog | select @{n="Time"; e={Get-Date -Format "HH:mm:ss"("$($_.time)")}},csuristem,scstatus | ? { $_.time -ge $time }
```

Thanks again Kev you're a good man. Hope this code helps someone else out there.

Here's

Comment: Thanks for sharing the corrected script back. It is a great start for something I need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your last line to:

```
$IISLog | select @{n="DateTime"; e={Get-Date ("$($_.date) $($_.time)")}},csuristem,scstatus | ? { $_.DateTime -ge $time }
```

In the select, we're concatenating the date and time fields, and converting them to a date object, then selecting rows where this field is greater than your $time variable.

You'll also need to change your $time variable:

```
$time = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-30)
```

You want a DateTime object here, not a string.

Comment: Hi Kev, thanks for the try but I just get the same output as before.

Comment: I see the problem. In line 2 of your script, remove the -Format parameter from $time. I'll update my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Sorry dude, no output now! I did try, before your suggestion, adding the -format to the line you added and got some different results but they seemed to be changing the time and reversing the results.

Comment: In the last line, when you're doing the select, and then filtering, you definitely want to be comparing to a DateTime object. If you're not getting any results, are you sure that there are actually 500 errors within the last 30 minutes?

Comment: absolutely positive there are 500 erros, i've made sure there are 500's all the way thro

Comment: Well then, I'm stumped. It works on my system. The only changes I made to your script are the two changes in my answer - line 2 to set the $time, and line 31 to select the date time, and filter it. And of course, changing the path to the IIS log files to reflect my system. No idea why it's not working for you.